# Structuring Nested Collections in RavenDB

Tags: nosql, ravendb

I've got a question about how I structure my data in RavenDB. As like most I'm coming from a relational database background and it feels slightly like I'm having to re-program my brain :).

Anyway. I have a utility which looks as below

```
{
  "Name": "Gas",
  "Calendars": [ 
    {
      "Name": "EFA"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Calendar"
    }
  ] 
}
```

And I have a contract. Whilst creating the contract I need to first pick a utility type. Then based upon that I need to pick a Calendar type.

For example, I would pick Gas and then I would pick EFA. My question is how should I store this information against the contract object. It almost feels like each of my calendars should have an id, but I'm guessing this is wrong? Or should I just be storing the text values?

Any advice on the correct way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can have internal objects have ids in RavenDB, but those are application managed, not managed by RavenDB.

Comment: I did contemplate this Ayende. However I wasn't sure if it was going against the RavenDB mindset?